# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/client/api/Vendor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Hey I am updating kotlinx coroutines to latest version in android. I am getting weird issue on lint check. I updated my version to `1.5.1` to `1.6.0` in my project.

**buidl.gradle(application)**

```
ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
        kotlin_serializtion_version = '1.5.21'
        kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.6.0"
        retrofit_version = '2.5.0'
        moshiVersion = "1.12.0"
        retrofit2_version = "2.5.0"
        okhttp3_version = "4.9.0"
        mockk_version = "1.10.4"
        picassoVersion = "2.71828"
        lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
        koin_version = "3.1.5"
        barcode_scanner_version = "16.1.1"
        camerax_version = "1.0.0"
        camera_view_version = "1.0.0-alpha22"
        stripe_version = "19.0.0"
        jacoco_version = "0.8.7"
        room_version = "2.3.0"
    }


dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_serializtion_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
```

**buidl.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    //Kotlin extensions library for Play Core
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

    //Android Kotlin extensions
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"

    //Unit test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.4.0'
    implementation "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacoco_version"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:${mockk_version}"

    //Moshi (JSON parser)
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    //Retrofit2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2_version"

    //Paging 3
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha07"

    //Okhttp3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3_version"

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlin_coroutines_version"

    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    //HTML parser
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'

    //Payments
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0'
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:$stripe_version"

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core"

    //Pager indicator
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'

    //Animations
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.2.2'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    //Loading images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //View container which can wrap content
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'

    //Phone Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'

    //Video player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.3'

    //Dependency injection - Koin AndroidX Scope features
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:$koin_version"
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:$koin_version"
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koin_version"

    //WorkManager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"

    // App Startup
    implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0"

    //Progress button extension
    implementation 'com.github.razir.progressbutton:progressbutton:2.1.0'

    //PDF Viewer
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    //Amplitude
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.25.2'

    //Salesforce chat
    implementation "com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.2.2"

    //Jumio
    implementation "com.jumio.android:core:3.9.2@aar"   // Jumio Core library
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv:3.9.2@aar"     // Netverify library
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv-barcode:3.9.2@aar"   // Barcode scanning
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv-mrz:3.9.2@aar" // MRZ scanning

    //AppsFlyer
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'

    // Code Scanner & Camera
    implementation "com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:$barcode_scanner_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camera_view_version"

    // Braze (marketing push notifications)
    implementation "com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:14.0.0"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"

    //Memory leak analysis - should only run in dev builds (devqaImplementation)
    //devqaImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'
}
```

Error what I am getting

```
Could not load custom lint check jar file /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/28f32124189df6c8d7d39ecfef6ee770/jetified-ui-graphics-1.0.5/jars/lint.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/client/api/Vendor
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.lint.UiGraphicsIssueRegistry.<init>(UiGraphicsIssueRegistry.kt:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.loadIssueRegistry(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:200)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.get(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:152)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.get(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:116)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.registerCustomDetectors(LintDriver.kt:494)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.kt:414)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.kt:256)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.kt:237)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.kt:255)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.runLint(LintGradleExecution.kt:259)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.lintSingleVariant(LintGradleExecution.kt:275)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.kt:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:117)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.lint(LintPerVariantTask.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:726)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:693)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
```